# How can I change style in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I need to change backgroundColor in main div
For example:

```
if(value === 20){
 div.background: orange
} else if(value === 30){
 div.background: red
} else {
 div.background: gray
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const value = 20;
    let divStyle = {};

    if (value === 20) {
      divStyle.color = "red";
    } else {
      divStyle.color = "blue";
    }

    return <div style={divStyle}>hey there</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/6m3jplvjw).